# Symbolic polyhedron of a monomial ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator\maxAss{maxAss}\DeclareMathOperator\conv{conv}$Let $I$ be a non-zero monomial ideal and $P$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb R_+ ^ {n+1}$ be its symbolic polyhedron: then
$$
\alpha(P)= \min \{a\cdot \mathbf{1}\mid  a \in P\},$$ where $\mathbf{1} =(1,\dotsc,1) \in\mathbb R_+ ^ {n+1}$.
 In this definition, why is $\alpha(P)$ defined to be the minimum of $a\cdot\mathbf{1}$ for all $a \in P$ instead of the infimum of all $a\cdot\mathbf{1}$ for all $a \in P$?

The symbolic polyhedron of a monomial ideal $I$ is the polyhedron $B \subseteq$ $\mathbb R_+ ^ {n+1}$ given by
$$
B = \bigcap_{P\in \maxAss(I)} \conv(L(Q_{\subseteq P})) 
$$
where $\maxAss(I)$ is the maximal associated primes of $I$ under inclusion and  $Q_{\subseteq P} = IR_P \cap R$ and $\conv(L(Q_{\subseteq P}))$ is the convex hull of the set of lattice points that are exponent vectors of  monomials in $Q_{\subseteq P}$.

Comment: What is a symbolic polyhedron?

Comment: Presumably this definition comes from somewhere—where?  Also, of course, the minimum *is* the infimum when it exists, so is your question why the minimum exists?